# Webpage loaded in a div not visible and the end of scrollbar of another div could not be seen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the pasted fiddle link I have 3 div tags in the html section. one div comprises the header part. Second div presents a tree structure and third div loads a webpage. In the result of the fiddle code, 1st div is there with header part. second div is also there with the expected tree structure but could not see the end of the scrollbar. Third div which should show an html page is not showing. 
https://jsfiddle.net/msridhar/qfq5su63/18/
The purpose of this entire code is to present 3 divs in one page and each should be scrollable in case of overflow. I don't want the default scroll bar that would be given by . Please help me with this problem.

HTML file:

```
<body class="disableScroll" style="height: 100%;">
<div id="headerDiv">
<img id="headerImg" src="./assets/Logo.png" width="280" height="125" alt="Logo"/>


<pre id="headerPre">
 Test Series
Cloud Solutions
</pre>                  
<hr id="headerHR">
</div>  
<div class="results1" style="width:250px; height:100%; border:1px solid #ff8000; margin-left:0; margin-top:130px;overflow:scroll;">
 <ul>
    <li item-selected='true'>Home</li>
    <li item-expanded='true'>Solutions
        <ul>
            <li>Education</li>
            <li>Financial services</li>
            <li>Government</li>
            <li>Manufacturing</li>
            <li>Solutions
                <ul>
                    <li>Consumer photo and video</li>
                    <li>Mobile</li>
                    <li>Rich Internet applications</li>
                    <li>Technical communication</li>
                    <li>Training and eLearning</li>
                    <li>Web conferencing</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>All industries and solutions</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>       
</div>  
<div class="results2" style="width:100%; height:100%; margin-left:280px;margin-top:130px; overflow:scroll;">  
</div>
```

CSS File:

```
html{
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
.disableScroll{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
 }  
#headerDiv{     
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
  width: 100vw;             
//border-bottom: 3px solid #808080;
}
#headerHR{                                              
   width: 100%;
   height: 1px;
}
#headerImg{
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
#headerPre{
  float: left;
  font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

Javascript file:

```
    $('.results1').jqxTree({       
   width: '250px',
   theme: 'energyblue'
    });                         
   $(".results2").load("https://fiddle.jshell.net/t5L1tywu/1/show/",function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the results1 style with

```
width:250px;height:100%;border:1px solid #ff8000;margin-left:0;margin-top:130px;overflow:scroll; float: left;
```

and results2 with

```
height:100%;margin-left:280px;margin-top:130px;overflow:scroll;
```

in this way in yuor fiddle you can see all the three div.
I don't have a solution for the scroll issue.